# Editor template with RTF output

Tags: c#, forms, ms-word, rtf

I need to create editor with templates for one company. Forms have a RichTextBox control. Therefore I want working with RTF - it's easy way... (Because they want edit output of this editor in external application - such as example MSWord.) And they want to have header and footer areas. How can I easiest create this areas and bind it into document? For generation valid RTF - for other editors (MSWord) and viewers, that will be able to process into this header and footer... This header and footer should be a template for one company documents... (These templates are in external RTF file - these are the logos...) Thank you.

Comment: Try to be clearer on what you need

Comment: OK - sorry - I need to bind RTF file with header and footer with RichTextBox output...